# Is there a data structure that can get value by key and get key by value both in Python?

Tags: python

Title might be a bit confusing, so here's an example, assume you have a really big `dict` like this:

```
{"James": “20492”， “Mike": "292", "Tony": "11134", "Timmy": "3984", ... }
```

Let's say all keys and values are unique, there're **no duplicates**. And I want to get `James` by providing id `20492`, or get `292` by providing `Mike`.

Well, besides for creating another "reverse" `dict` like this: `{"20492": "James", ... }`, what other choices(better be elegant) do I have?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict/0.1.2

Comment: A Python dict is basically a hash table and hash tables have constant time look up. But a fundamental attribute of hashing is it is one way. You simply can't reverse a hash. You may be able to use a list of tuples but you will lose speed as list look ups are linear time.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That's implemented with just two dicts (although I can't see any other way to do it for arbitrary keys and values).

Comment: The implementation shouldn't matter. I believe the OP was looking for something which is short and easy to use. This library seems to fit the bill. Btw, if the lists are constant, I would just use two dictionaries. Build one from data and then build the other from the first.

Answer (score 0):

The best data structure for this (short of a database) is a dictionary.  You would have to implement a reverse dictionary as well.

If you want to go the database route, and your data set is not large, you can use sqlite (bundled with recent versions of Python) and use the special `:memory:` location to create an in-memory database. It should be quite fast.